# How to count the Gap between dates in SQL Server with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the GAP (In days) between records in one Table, I'm using SQL Server.

So far, I was able to get the gap (in days) between dates, but there was an issue with the overlapping dates.

Here is the setup script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
   RoomTypeId INT,
   BedId INT,
   StartDate DATE,
   EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (RoomTypeId, BedId, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES (39, 229, '2019-08-03', '2019-08-04'),
       (39, 229, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-08'),
       (40, 231, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-08'),
       (41, 238, '2019-08-02', '2019-08-03'),
       (42, 233, '2019-08-02', '2019-08-03'),
       (42, 233, '2019-08-04', '2019-08-05'),
       (42, 234, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-05'),
       (43, 241, '2019-08-01', '2019-08-01'),
       (43, 241, '2019-08-15', '2019-08-16'),
       (43, 241, '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30'),
       (45, 245, '2019-08-03', '2019-08-06'),
       (45, 244, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-05'),
       (45, 244, '2019-08-08', '2019-08-10'),
       (45, 244, '2019-08-17', '2019-08-19'),
       (46, 239, '2019-08-03', '2019-08-04'),
       (46, 239, '2019-08-05', '2019-08-05'),
       (48, 250, '2019-08-16', '2019-08-18'),
       (49, 274, '2019-08-06', '2019-08-11'),
       (49, 275, '2019-08-08', '2019-08-10');
```

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT 
    p.RoomTypeId,
    p.EndDateSeq1,
    p.StartDateSeq2,
    SUM(p.GAP) AS [GAP]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t.RoomTypeId,
         t.EndDate AS [EndDateSeq1],
         t2.StartDate AS [StartDateSeq2],
         DATEDIFF(d, t.EndDate,t2.StartDate) AS [GAP]
     FROM 
         #Temp t
     LEFT JOIN 
         #Temp t2 ON t2.RoomTypeId = t.RoomTypeId
                  AND (t2.StartDate > t.EndDate OR t2.StartDate = t.EndDate)) p
GROUP BY 
    p.RoomTypeId, p.EndDateSeq1, p.StartDateSeq2
ORDER BY 
    p.RoomTypeId, p.EndDateSeq1 ASC
```

Result:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
║ RoomTypeId ║ EndDateSeq1 ║ StartDateSeq2 ║ GAP  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
║         39 ║ 2019-08-04  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 1    ║
║         39 ║ 2019-08-08  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         40 ║ 2019-08-08  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         41 ║ 2019-08-03  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         42 ║ 2019-08-03  ║ 2019-08-04    ║ 1    ║
║         42 ║ 2019-08-03  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 2    ║
║         42 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 0    ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-01  ║ 2019-08-01    ║ 0    ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-01  ║ 2019-08-15    ║ 14   ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-01  ║ 2019-08-29    ║ 28   ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-16  ║ 2019-08-29    ║ 13   ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-30  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 0    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-08    ║ 3    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-17    ║ 12   ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-06  ║ 2019-08-08    ║ 2    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-06  ║ 2019-08-17    ║ 11   ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-10  ║ 2019-08-17    ║ 7    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-19  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         46 ║ 2019-08-04  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 1    ║
║         46 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 0    ║
║         48 ║ 2019-08-18  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         49 ║ 2019-08-10  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         49 ║ 2019-08-11  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩══════╝
```

Expected Results:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════╗
║ RoomTypeId ║ EndDateSeq1 ║ StartDateSeq2 ║ GAP  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════╣
║         39 ║ 2019-08-04  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 1    ║
║         39 ║ 2019-08-08  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         40 ║ 2019-08-08  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         41 ║ 2019-08-03  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         42 ║ 2019-08-03  ║ 2019-08-04    ║ 1    ║
║         42 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ NULL          ║ 0    ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-01  ║ 2019-08-15    ║ 14   ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-16  ║ 2019-08-29    ║ 13   ║
║         43 ║ 2019-08-30  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-05  ║ 2019-08-06    ║ 1    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-06  ║ 2019-08-08    ║ 2    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-10  ║ 2019-08-17    ║ 7    ║
║         45 ║ 2019-08-19  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         46 ║ 2019-08-04  ║ 2019-08-05    ║ 1    ║
║         48 ║ 2019-08-18  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
║         49 ║ 2019-08-11  ║ NULL          ║ NULL ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩══════╝
```

The goal was to get the gap with respect to the overlapping dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow your results.

I think the problem is a combination of gaps-and-islands along with "fill-in-gaps".  That is, you need to combine the existing data that overlaps.  Then you need to get the pieces in-between.

You can identify the overlaps by using a cumulative max of the end date from preceding rows.  When it is less than or equal to the current start, then you have a new "island".  The result is aggregation and `lead()`.

The code looks like this:

```
select roomTypeId, grp, max(enddate), lead(min(startdate)) over (partition by roomtypeid order by min(startdate)),
       datediff(day, max(enddate), lead(min(startdate)) over (partition by roomtypeid order by min(startdate)) )
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate > startdate then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by RoomTypeId order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(enddate) over (partition by RoomTypeId
                                      order by startdate
                                      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                     ) as prev_enddate
            from temp t
           ) t
     ) t
group by roomtypeid, grp
order by roomtypeid, min(startdate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2fac2a60d0d9c362cdc0a7585f719020) is the db<>fiddle.

The results are subtly different, but they make more sense to me.

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks @Gordon, I just need to remove this one records [image.png](https://postimg.cc/4mgJn1Gw), I tried but i was getting an issue [image.png](https://postimg.cc/t1hKKKZj)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that:

```sql
select
    main.*,
    iif(DATEDIFF(d, EndDate, nextStartDate)>0, DATEDIFF(d, EndDate, nextStartDate), 0) as GAP
from
(
    select
        RoomTypeId,
        lead(StartDate) over (partition by RoomTypeId order by StartDate asc) as nextStartDate,
        StartDate,
        EndDate
    from 
        tab1
) main;
```

sql fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94c1585c246e18b5d4bcc527997cdfc1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_Number()` concept here.

Try this

```
SELECT 
    p.RoomTypeId,
    p.EndDateSeq1,
    p.StartDateSeq2,
    SUM(p.GAP) AS [GAP]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.RoomTypeId,
        t.EndDate AS [EndDateSeq1],
        t2.StartDate AS [StartDateSeq2],
        DATEDIFF(d, t.EndDate,t2.StartDate) AS [GAP],
        ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY  t.RoomTypeId,t.StartDate ORDER By t2.StartDate) RN
    FROM #Temp t
    LEFT JOIN #Temp t2 ON t2.RoomTypeId = t.RoomTypeId 
        AND (t2.StartDate > t.EndDate) 
) p
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY p.RoomTypeId, p.EndDateSeq1, p.StartDateSeq2
ORDER BY p.RoomTypeId, p.EndDateSeq1 ASC
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=787f4e068fc8bb180d644892ee112e4d)

Comment: Hi @Vignesh, thank you for your answer, im not sure why the result from the SQL Fiddle is different from my local, here is what im getting from your query [Img](https://i.postimg.cc/nLn0HtvQ/1.png)

Comment: Hi @Vignesh, the result was almost there, is just that the overlapping dates are still there. Thanks